# Cell Reference based on sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have one workbook.

In it I have several sheet that I renamed with number with the first sheet is the database I want to pull the number.

**sheet1** renamed to A : Contain the data that I want to pull from
**sheet2** renamed to 1: the formula in cell `B3` should be `=A!B1`
**sheet3** renamed to 2: the formula in cell `B3` should be `=A!B2`
**sheet4** renamed to 3: the formula in cell `B3` should be `=A!B3`
**sheet5** renamed to 4: the formula in cell `B3` should be `=A!B4`

I can pull the sheet name that I renamed to digit above with this formula

```
IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(CELL("filename";$A$1);LEN(CELL("filename";$A$1))-FIND("]";CELL("filename";$A$1))));"This workbook never saved";RIGHT(CELL("filename";$A$1);LEN(CELL("filename";$A$1))-FIND("]";CELL("filename";$A$1))))
```

But I can't use it to change the cell reference so that in sheet `1` is `=A!B1` and in sheet `2`is `=A!B2`
the cell reference is changed whenever I changed the sheet name.

Can anyone help me with those, so the formula is more like this `=A!B(sheetname)`

Comment: Are you familiar with the function INDIRECT?

Comment: It might be more useful to include why do you need to reference sheet names instead of normal cells. You might have better answer if you give us an example of data and how you want to handle it, thus preventing needing to use INDIRECT at all.

Comment: It simply as the question. I already tested the INDIRECT, and its worked as I wanted to. but with many cell i'm planning to use Im afraid its not efficient.  
So I'm planning to use my formula to grab the sheet value in cell `A3` and use all other cell to use the value of that cell as the cell reference. so its like =`A!B(A3)`. do you know the formula to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=INDIRECT("A!B"&yourformula)
```

One of the downsides of `INDIRECT` is if you change your sheet `A` name, for example `Kitchen`, the formula will not update to `"Kitchen!B"&yourformula`.

And please remember that `INDIRECT` is an unelegant way to solve problems. It is horrendously slow, especially when you are dealing with a LOT of INDIRECTs!!

Comment: is there other solution? cause I'm planning use a lot of this more that 500 cell in every sheet. and the around 50 sheet in the workbook.

Comment: I'm planning to use my formula in cell `A3` and use all other cell to use the value of that cell as the cell reference. so its like `=A!B(A3)`. does anyone know the formula to do it?